# Cannot add drawableStart/drawableLeft with passwordToggleEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I also tried adding it using the java code;

```
password.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

I've also searched what solves this but to no avail I only find drawableStart which is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```

try:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left,top,right,bottom)
```

as compare to:

```
setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds
```

Comment: you are  trying to set the compound drawable pragmatically and you using 
"password.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);"
as compare to this try this
"password.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.yourIconName, 0, 0, 0);"

Answer (score 3):

it works for me :

[image]

use `TextInputLayout` it has `password toggle` functionallity.
as follow

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:hint="enter name"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent">
         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share_red"
             android:drawablePadding="10dp"
             android:inputType="numberPassword"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:drawableStart="@drawable/share_red" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Yes i am using textinputlayout and it is where the problem is.

Comment: try this it may helpyou